# Not able to receive the file at background.js when sending it from server/index.js (making a chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, websocket, socket.io, google-chrome-devtools

So, I want to share files over a **socket.io** network in a chrome extension.
My code-flow is as follows :

1. I have a *file-input* field in the popup, where the user uploads the file. I receive the file at **popup.js** and send the corresponding buffer to the background.js(where the instance of socket.io is present) , here the code :

//popup.js

```
shareButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  if (fileInputElement.files.length === 0) {
    alert("Choose the file you want to send ");
    return;
  }

  let file = fileInputElement.files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader(); 

  reader.onload = () => {
    let buffer = new Uint8Array(reader.result);

    console.log(buffer); 

    initFileShare({ filename: file.name, bufferSize: buffer.length }, buffer);
  };

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
});

function initFileShare(metadata, buffer) {
  const bufferArray = Array.from(buffer);
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ event: "file-share", metadata, bufferArray});
}
```

2. The **background.js** listens for the event and passes it to the server file (index.js) :

```
  if (message.event === "file-share") {
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(message.buffer);

    socket.emit("file-share", {
      metadata: message.metadata,
      buffer: buffer,
      targetRoomId: curr_roomID,
    });
  }
```

3. inside the index.js, I have a socket listener that sends chunks of the file to the client until whole file is sent  :

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`Connection made to socket id ${socket.id}`);

socket.on("file-share", ({ metadata, buffer, targetRoomId }) => {
 
console.log('metadata : ' , metadata  ) ; 

if (buffer && buffer.slice instanceof Function) {
  console.log('Buffer:');
} else {
  console.log('Invalid buffer:', buffer);
}

console.log('targetRoomId' , targetRoomId) ; 

  // Emit the file metadata to the target socket
  io.to(targetRoomId).emit("file-metadata", metadata);

  // Send file chunks to the target socket
  let chunkSize = 1024;
  let initialChunk = 0;

  function sendNextChunk() {
    if (initialChunk < metadata.bufferSize) {
      let start = initialChunk;
      let end = Math.min(initialChunk + chunkSize, metadata.bufferSize);
      let filePiece = buffer.slice(start, end);

      console.log(metadata.bufferSize, filePiece.length);
 
      io.to(targetRoomId).emit("file-chunk", filePiece);

      initialChunk += chunkSize;
 
      // Check if all chunks have been sent
      if (initialChunk >= metadata.bufferSize) {
        console.log("poori file send ho gyi hai ");
        socket.emit("file-sent", metadata); 
      } else {
        setTimeout(sendNextChunk, 0);
      }
    }
  }

  // Start sending chunks
  sendNextChunk();
});
```

4. the background.js listens for the **'file-chunk'** event at the client side :

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {

  let newFile = {
    buffer: [],
    metadata: null,
  };


  socket.on("file-chunk", (chunk) => {
    let chunkSize = 1024;

    newFile.buffer.push(chunk);
    console.log(newFile.buffer);

    if (newFile.metadata) {
      console.log("Buffer size and metadata buffer size:",newFile.buffer.length,newFile.metadata.bufferSize);

      if (newFile.buffer.length * chunkSize >= newFile.metadata.bufferSize) {
        console.log("All chunks received. Initiating download...");
        console.log("Received buffer size:", newFile.buffer.length);

        let receivedFile = new Blob(newFile.buffer);

        console.log("receivedFile", receivedFile);

        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
          event: "downloadFile",
          buffer: receivedFile,
          filename: newFile.metadata.filename,
        });

        newFile = {};
        alert("Yayy! File received ");
      }
    }
  });
```

The **blob** which gets created inside the background.js after complete file is sent , is not what it should be. I mean the final size of the blob should be equal to the file's size, but it is not.
**Due to which I am not able to receive the original file at client side**, I mean that when I download the received file it is just a blank document which says `'[object][object]'`

Let me explain further , I tried doing the same thing with the same code , by making a simple web app to share files over socket connection , and it worked magically right.

Lets suppose I am uploading a ~5kb file , notice the blob size in the output :

*with chrome extension* :
[image: with chrome extension]

*with web-app* :
[image: web app]

Answer (score 0):

`chrome` messaging doesn't support binary data types in Chrome. Use the standard `navigator.serviceWorker` messaging mechanism instead.

// background.js

```js
/** @type MessagePort */
let port;

self.onmessage = evt => {
  if (evt.data === 'port') {
    port = evt.ports[0];
    port.onmessage = onPortMessage;
  }
}

function onPortMessage(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

// popup.js

```js
async function initSWPort() {
  const mc = new MessageChannel();
  navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage('port', [mc.port2]);
  return mc.port1;
}

async function usageExample() {
  const port = initSWPort();
  port.postMessage({ foo: new Blob(['bar']) });
  port.onmessage = evt => console.log(evt);
}
```